# CodeMirror MarkText

Tags: javascript, html, codemirror

In the codemirror documentation, they have a method called markText (http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api_marker). I have looked over the documentation and still do not understand what to do.

```
var word = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('words'), {
    mode: "text/html",
});
word.markText({1,1},{3,1}, readOnly: true);
```

The code above does not seam to work. Please tell me how to correctly use the markText method.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some more thinking I found out how to do it.

```
word.markText({line:1,ch:1},{line:3,ch:1},{readOnly:true});
```

I simply forgot that it had to be an object. My bad.

Comment: Thanks. I had the same problem. Just adding that you can have multiple flags in the 3rd argument: { collapsed: true, replacedWith: document.createElement("hr") }

Comment: Is there any way to highlight all the text in textarea or must we use `for` loop for each line?